# Apache Ignite Spring Data Extension Dependency Error

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-data, ignite

I am new to Apache Ignite and learning how to use the Ignite Spring Data Extension and am having a dependency compatibility problem.

Dependency used:

1. Spring Data commons 2.7.2 (org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:2.7.2)
2. ignite-core 2.13.0 (org.apache.ignite:ignite-core:2.13.0)
3. ignite-spring 2.13.0 (org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring:2.13.0)
4. ignite-spring-boot-thin-client-autoconfigure-ext  2.13.0 (org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-boot-thin-client-autoconfigure-ext:2.13.0)
5. ignite-indexing 2.13.0 (org.apache.ignite:ignite-indexing:2.13.0)
6. ignite-spring-data-2.2-ext 1.0.0 (org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-data-2.2-ext:1.0.0) OR ignite-spring-data-ext 2.0.0 (org.apache.ignite:ignite-spring-data-ext:2.0.0)

Course of action:

According to [the documentation](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-data), I should pick a version of Spring Data Commons, Ignite dependencies and the Ignite Spring Data Extension.  So I picked the latest for everything (as shown above).  Then the documentation said I should use ignite-spring-data-2.2-ext as I am using Spring Data 2.7.2 (>= 2.2).  So I tried and ran into the following maven build error:

> java: name clash: deleteAllById(java.lang.Iterable) in org.apache.ignite.springdata22.repository.IgniteRepository and deleteAllById(java.lang.Iterable<? extends ID>) in org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository have the same erasure, yet neither overrides the other*

Googling led me to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70688487/igniterepository-crudrepository-have-the-same-erasure-yet-neither-overrides-the) and [the public maven repository](https://search.maven.org/search?q=ignite-spring-data-ext), it seems a new version that fixes the method signature had been out; so I switched ignite-spring-data-ext 2.0.0.  But then I ran into another app startup ClassNotFoundException (Spring Dependency):

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
    at org.apache.ignite.springdata.repository.config.IgniteRepositoriesRegistar.getExtension(IgniteRepositoriesRegistar.java:34) ~[ignite-spring-data-ext-2.0.0.jar:2.0.0]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.registerBeanDefinitions(RepositoryBeanDefinitionRegistrarSupport.java:100) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.lambda$loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars$1(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:396) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsFromRegistrars(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:395) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitionsForConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:157) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassBeanDefinitionReader.java:129) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:343) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564) ~[spring-context-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295) [spring-boot-2.7.3.jar:2.7.3]
    at com.example.ignitespringdatalocal.IgniteSpringDataLocalApplication.main(IgniteSpringDataLocalApplication.java:21) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:338) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 19 common frames omitted*
```

So I wonder:

1. What maven dependency am I missing?
2. Is there any table that shows which version of Ignite Spring Data Extension supports which version of Spring Data?
3. Ignite team, please kindly update this part of the documentation as I feel a bit lost over my troubleshooting, thanks!

In the meantime, I will keep googling which dependency am I missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the "org.springframework:spring-tx" dependency is missing:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

For some reason, it is only listed on the Spring Transactions [page](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/extensions-and-integrations/spring/spring-tx) in the documentation, which doesn't look right. I've filed documentation [ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IGNITE-17640) for that.

Comment: Thank you so much Igor!  That solved my issue, very much appreciated!